# Kibana: visualizing simple log as table

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I'd like to visualize logged events like an aggregated log file: as a table.

My testdata was created by an sample Java application using the `net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashSocketAppender` (an Logback JSON appender) and an `http_poller`, polling a Spring actuator.

As my first step, I'd like to visualize just the logback messages ordered by time. I went to discover and added message, but sadly the result looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the first line, which actually contains a message, displays`{"@timestamp":"2016-04-15T15:28:00.104+02:00","@version":1,"message":"accounts-service byOwner() found: []","logger_name":"io.pivotal.microservices.accounts.AccountsController","thread_name":"main","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"HOSTNAME":"ham00705"}`

**How can I just display the content of message**, in this case `"accounts-service byOwner() found: []","logger_name":"io.pivotal.microservices.accounts.AccountsController"`?

and **How do I hide events without a message**?

### -- Update --

a sample message looks like:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.04.15",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "AVQaK4Ng7SD5aGZ_l8Xy",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "{\"@timestamp\":\"2016-04-15T15:28:00.104+02:00\",\"@version\":1,\"message\":\"accounts-service byOwner() found: []\",\"logger_name\":\"io.pivotal.microservices.accounts.AccountsController\",\"thread_name\":\"main\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"level_value\":20000,\"HOSTNAME\":\"ham00705\"}\r",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-04-15T13:45:37.085Z",
    "path": "D:\\Coden\\Projects\\Git\\microservice-logging\\logstash2\\test-data\\app-min.log.json",
    "host": "ham00705"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1460727937085
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1460727937085
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try displaying 'message.message'?

Comment: Please, show the whole logstash message

Comment: Your message field is messed up, you should fix it first.